# REQUEST_DENIED for google geocoding API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

```
 geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        document.getElementById('latitude').setAttribute('value', latitude);
        document.getElementById('longitude').setAttribute('value',  longitude);
        var lat = parseFloat(latitude);
        var lng = parseFloat(longitude);
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    document.getElementById('physicaladdress').setAttribute('value', results[1].formatted_address);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
       console.log(""+status);
    }
});
```

This is my javascript file where i am trying to get latitude and longitude from zip code ,it is working fine in localhost but not when it is hosted live(say aws)

{} ,this i am giving into the app.blade.php , any help would be much appreciated sorry if i am missing anything while asking question.

Comment: Does the `REQUEST_DENIED` response come with any other useful information. I would expect it would. Can you please show us the COMPLETE error message

Comment: REQUEST_DENIED (the error i am getting is this only)

Comment: I suppose you **do** have a google maps API key ... right?

Comment: No i do not have  i am simply putting this  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> inside of app.blade.php ,and even if i have the api key i donot know where to put it as i am new to laravel, sorry for bad english

Comment: check the browser developer tools console and network info tab - you'll probably get more information there - oh, you dont' have an API key - that's the problem then

Comment: as for where to put the key [read some documentation or a tutorial or two](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Comment: as for where to put the key -Thank you so much